# How can I improve the performance of my database queries?

Tags: c#, mysql, performance

I'm trying to simplify my code and make the search a little bit faster. right now, depending, it's taking more than 15 Sec to fill my DataGridView.

I tried to join the 2 SQL sentence together, but failed.
Also, I have no idea how to simplify the check of the Stock etc..
I tried to enter all the information to an array and then pass it as the DataGridView Source, rather than inserting line by line, but without effect for the search term.

```
conn.Open();
MySqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction();

// Getting the Product
string sql = "SELECT id, typ, generation, configuration, revision"
           + " FROM product"
           + " WHERE typ = '" + comboBox_type.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";

MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn, trans);
MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

List<KeyValuePair<int, string>> productList = new List<KeyValuePair<int, string>>();

while (rdr.Read())
{
   string produkt = rdr[1] + "-" + string.Format("{0:X2}", rdr[2]) + string.Format("{0:X2}", rdr[3]) + string.Format("{0:X2}", rdr[4]);
   int id = Convert.ToInt32(rdr[0]);               
   productList.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, string>(id, produkt));
}
rdr.Close();

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> productKeyValue in productList)
{
   sql = "SELECT COUNT(c.id)"
       + " FROM component_product ctp"
       + " JOIN component c ON ctp.id = c.id"
       + " WHERE ctp.product = " + productKeyValue.Key + " AND c.`status` = 3 AND ctp.outdated = 0";

   cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn, trans);
   rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

   int stock = Convert.ToInt32(rdr[0]);

   rdr.Close();

   int stockDiff = stock, ordered = 0, reserved = 0;

   List<string> shortage = new List<string>();
   List<string> deliveries = new List<string>();
   List<string> planing = new List<string>();

   List<CommonHelper.DeliveryEntry> pm_dict = ch.GetProductMovement(productKeyValue.Key, conn, trans);

   foreach (CommonHelper.DeliveryEntry de in pm_dict)
   {
      int amount = de.Amount;
      string strDate = CommonHelper.MaterialText.DeliveryTimestamp(de.Timestamp);
      bool confirmed = (de.Confirmed == CommonHelper.DeliveryState.Confirmed);
      stockDiff += amount;
      if (amount >= 0)
      {
         ordered += amount;
         deliveries.Add(CommonHelper.MaterialText.Deliveries(confirmed, amount, stockDiff, strDate));
         planing.Add("+" + String.Format("{0,5}", amount) + " (" + strDate + ")                                    Stand: " + stockDiff.ToString());
      }
      else
      {
         reserved += amount;
         if (stockDiff < 0)
         {
            shortage.Add(CommonHelper.MaterialText.Shortages(amount, stockDiff, strDate));
         }

         planing.Add("                           " + String.Format("{0,5}", amount) + " (" + strDate + ")            Stand: " + stockDiff.ToString());
      }
   }

   string[] rowDate = new string[] {
   productKeyValue.Value,
   stock.ToString(),
   ordered.ToString(),
   reserved.ToString(),
   string.Join(" \r\n", shortage),
   string.Join(" \r\n", deliveries),
   string.Join("\r\n", planing)
   };

   dataGridView_inventorylist.Rows.Add(rowDate);
}
```

Comment: Do you have the proper indexes on your tables? When SQL queries have performance issues, this is the first thing to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should consolidate your two queries with a join operation. You're allowed to use subqueries as virtual tables.

This aggregating (GROUP BY) subquery returns one row for each `c.id` value.

```
                 SELECT COUNT(*) count, c.id
                   FROM component_product ctp
                   JOIN component c ON ctp.id = c.id
                  WHERE c.status = 3
                    AND ctp.outdated = 0
                  GROUP BY c.id
```

Then, you join that to your other query. I used `LEFT JOIN` so the entire query will report items that have no counts. A plain `JOIN` suppresses rows with no counts.

Try something like this:

```
 SELECT count.count,
        p.id, p.typ, p.generation, p.configuration, p.revision
   FROM product p
   LEFT JOIN (
                 SELECT COUNT(*) count, c.id
                   FROM component_product ctp
                   JOIN component c ON ctp.id = c.id
                  WHERE c.status = 3
                    AND ctp.outdated = 0
                 GROUP BY c.id 
        ) count ON p.id = count.id
  WHERE typ = '" + comboBox_type.SelectedValue.ToString() + "'";
```

Then, populate your grid using the rows of just this one query. Get rid of the `productlist` collection entirely, and get rid of the loop that runs a query for every element of that collection.  In other words, retrieve what you need with just one query, rather than one plus one-for-every-product. This should resolve your performance problem.

Comment: I suspect that `ch.GetProductMovement(productKeyValue.Key, conn, trans);` is heading to the database as well, based on `conn, trans` being passed in, further slowing things down with database round-trips

Comment: @O. Jones I tried your query in HeidiSQL but I get **SQL Error (1054): Unknown column in 'c.id' in 'on clause'**. I Presume it's because in the first Select the table _`component c`_ is not known. I tried to fix it by adding in `FROM product p, component c`, but then I get the same error except that this time it's p.id

Comment: OH, sorry, typo.  See my edit. It should be `) count ON p.id = count.id`

Comment: Thank you it staved me around 150 millisecond which is a step in the right direction. As @Rob mentioned the real problem is with the SQL query  in 'ch.GetProductMovement(productKeyValue.Key, conn, trans)' as he is calling this query for every p.id from the first query.

Comment: Right, I didn't spot the repeated calls to `ch.GetProduct...`. The principle of my answer is still valid. If you can create a query or a view to fetch all the information you need in a single result set, everything gets faster. Repeated / iterated queries for single rows cause slowness.